# jQuery .focus() not working in Safari (desktop) on search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I have a search field that is hidden, and when a user clicks on the search icon, it opens and I want to bring focus to the search input immediately so the user does not have to click twice. It works perfect in Chrome, but not in Safari (desktop). I saw some other suggestions that wrapping it in a timeout will work, but still no dice. Any thoughts?

jQuery:

```
$search       = $('.header--search-container');
$searchInput  = $('.header--search-input input[type=search]');

  $search.click(function(){
    $searchInput.toggleClass('search-active');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('header .header--search-input .search-field').focus();
    }, 1);
  });
```

HTML (Don't really think its needed but just so you can see... Also redacted is the `<header>` element) :

```
<div class="header--search-input">
      <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://example.com/">
       <label>
         <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
         <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search &hellip;" value="" name="s" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
       </form>        
 </div>
        <div class="header--search-container">
          <svg> 
           .. redacted for legibility on stack overflow ..
          </svg>

        </div>
```

Comment: have you tried using scrollIntoView() after the focus

Comment: you tried with `dom` `.focus()` `$('header .header--search-input .search-field')[0].focus();` ?

Comment: @Maxqueue i'm not sure that would be the answer? The element is in view already.  -- Just tried, no dice.

Comment: @itsgoingdown hmm, that doesn't appear to work either.

Comment: @itsgoingdown that also broke it in chrome

Comment: The delay of `setTimeout` function is in milliseconds. Try making it 1 second. `setTimeout(function(){ $('header .header--search-input .search-field').focus(); }, 1000);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a higher `setTimeout` value works.

```
  $search.click(function(){
    $searchInput.toggleClass('search-active');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('header .header--search-input .search-field').focus();
    }, 500);
  });
```